# Dynamic Razor data source

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to use Razor Engine as a standalone template engine. This is working great except that I don't know which are the properties that will be passed to Razor therefore I can't declare an object listing my vars. I currently do this using a dictionary, allowing me to write things like that :

```
@Model.Vars["MyProperty"]
```

But I would like to be able to simply write :

```
@MyProperty
```

Is there some way to do this ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why doesn't @Model.MyProperty work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some razor syntax to provide intellisense for your view:

```
@inherits MyNamespace.MoreNamespace.MyCustomRazorModel<MyModelType>
```

As long as your `MyCustomRazorModel` implements the required `Write`, `WriteLiteral` etc methods, then everything should work correctly, and you could use the following in your views:

```
@MyProperty
```

Assuming you had a definition like so:

```
public class MyCustomRazorModel<T>
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I mention that your backing Razor implementation should probably be Generic simply so that you can re-use it with whatever model you want for templating. That is also how the Razor engine works in ASP.NET, by providing a Generic model that exposes the model in the `@Model` property.

**EDIT**

For example, take a look at the following class to see how the framework guys did it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg402107(v=vs.108).aspx

This is the backing view for the RazorEngine in ASP.NET. For standalone implementations, you would make a backing type for the view to inherit like this.